# Unable to find a suitable output format for ' : Invalid argument

Tags: ffmpeg

`ffmpeg -i a.webm -i b.webm -filter_complex '[0:v]pad=iw*2:ih[int];[int][1:v]overlay=W/2:0[vid]' -map [vid] -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -preset veryfast outputfin.webm`

This was meant to be a simple code to merge two videos side-by-side. However, it is throwing the following error:

```
'NULL @ 0x55aafb8828e0] Unable to find a suitable output format for '
: Invalid argument
```

What is the error here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3 problems:

1. Your command works in Linux, but I don't think Windows likes single quotes. Use double quotes.
2. [hstack](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#hstack) (or [vstack](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#vstack)) is much easier then pad + overlay.
3. Only VP8 or VP9 or AV1 video and Vorbis or Opus audio and WebVTT subtitles are supported for WebM. You have two options to fix that:

   - Change output to `outputfin.mp4` for H.264 video + AAC audio in MP4.
   - Or remove `-c:v libx264 -crf 23 -preset veryfast` and it will by default output VP9 video + Opus audio in WebM.

Example:

```
ffmpeg -i a.webm -i b.webm -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]hstack" -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -preset veryfast outputfin.mp4
```